# google app engine adding on a colon when using url helpers

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel

I am running laravel 4 on google app engine and it is adding a colon on when i call any of the url helper functions.

i have followed this guide in implementing laravel four

http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel-4-on-google-appengine-for-php/

But there is no mention of the issue i am having. When i run laravel 4 through mamp on my local machine i do not get the issue

problem:
gae has this-

www.myapp.com:/css/bootstrap.css

locally the url helper works fine and returns the following url without the colon

localhost/myapp/css/bootstrap.css

any ideas on whats going on? could be a laravel problem? a gae problem? or a php?

Comment: Can you add more info on the specific helper method(s) you're using and the values you're passing to them?

Comment: I'm just using the standard url() function- http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls

Comment: Sorry, I can't repro this - e.g. for me on local dev appserver, "url('contact-us')" generates "http://localhost:8080/contact-us", and for the deployed app it generates: "http://myapp.appspot.com/contact-us".